# (Javascript , Chrome) query tab id and then access its elements

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, tabs

I would like to get elements from chrome tab with a certain URL, it does not have to be active. so far I have:

```
Test()

function Test() {
chrome.tabs.query({url: "https://www.somewebsite.com/*"}, function(results) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(results[0].id,{code: 'El = document.getElementsByClassName("someclass")'});
console.log(El);
})
}
```

Maybe it has to be done through a content script file?
I have this code placed in my background.js file. Given the proper URL and Class this function will not return the Element. Why?
Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: When do you want this code to run?

Comment: Well lets say I have an interval set for the background page to loop every 30 seconds, if the time of day is at a certain hour it will call Test() and get information from an element within a tab with a specific URL.

Comment: the weird thing is if I call:

`chrome.tabs.executeScript(result[0].id,{code:"document.body.style.backgroundColor='red'"});`

it will manipulate the right page, but how can I get elements from that page into variables?

Comment: Oh, I got what you mean. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background script is executed only once when chrome launches. Instead of writing this inside a function which you call in the same file, you have to put it in some kind of event listener. This code should stay in the background file, but has to be triggered by something, not just executed on extension load.

EDIT: Oh, I see, you're trying to pass the element to the background script. You can't.

Background scripts have access to the whole chrome APIs but not to the page content. The script you write in `executeScript` runs on the tab you specified, so the variables are available to other code within that tab, not within your background script. Extension code that can run on the page and edit its content is either sent using `executeScript` or put in content scripts.

If you want to share information between various layers of an extension, you need to use messages. They work like events and listeners. [Read the docs here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). You'll be able to pass data like numbers and strings, but not the actual HTMLElement. So any code that manipulates the DOM has to run on the tab itself.

If your code is small and simple, you could just write it in the `executeScript` call instead.

Comment: Yes, for testing purposes I am relying on executing the code immediately after reloading the extension. My background page normally has an interval that loops every 30 seconds and this code would be called based on several factors, including the time of day.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there does not appear to be a way to manipulate elements in another tab from the background.js;

```
Test();

function Test() {
 chrome.tabs.query({
    url: "https://www.google.com/*"
   }, function(results) {
    if (results.length < 1) { //if there is no tab open with google.com
     console.log("Tab not found, creating new tab");
     chrome.tabs.create({
      "url": "https://www.google.com/",
      "selected": true
     }, null);
     chrome.tabs.query({
       url: "https://www.google.com/*"
      }, function(results) {
       if (results.length >= 1) {
        console.log("Found google.com in the new tab");
       }
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(results[0].id, {
        code: "foo = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); console.log(foo,' This is sent from the active tab'); 

         chrome.storage.local.set({
         'foo': foo[0]
        });
        "},function(foo) {chrome.storage.local.get("
        foo ", function(foo) {console.log(foo , 'This has retrieved foo right after saving it to storage.');});});
       });
      }
     });
   }
   search()
   function search(result) {
    chrome.storage.local.get("foo", function(result) {
       console.log(result, 'This has retrieved foo from storage in a separate function within background.js');});
       }
```

the first console log will show the html collection object for the inputs from google.com inside the google.com tab console, the other two will show blank objects in the background.js console. Thanks, I will find another solution.